# Geospatial Query at Google App Engine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, geospatial, geopoints

I read the following post

[Querying Geopt with Objectify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31920968/querying-geopt-with-objectify/31924764#31924764)

This is exactly what I need for my application. At the end of the post I read that the Geospatial Search is in alpha stadium but the post is already one year old.

I cannot find any information about the status of Geospatial Queries at Google App Engine. Is it still in Alpha stadium or can I use in production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so for everyone who is interested in: today 27. Jan 2017 Geospatial Queries are still in Alpha stadium.

You need to create a search index of mode geospatial for your Geo Point Property and this is not allowed