# Find nearest location with Google Datastore and objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, datastore

I am looking for code to find the nearest location.

Currently storing - latitude and longitude in the entity (ie address). when user search it, want to display the result with 2km radius.

User entity:

```
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45378268/search-10-nearest-locations-in-datastore/45602189#45602189

Answer (score 0):

Geospatial queries are not supported at this moment.

There used to be some [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20161013230027/https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch), but seems to be deleted from AppEngine docs.

You may want to take a look into [geohash](https://github.com/kungfoo/geohash-java) library.

Comment: is there any unit test to test it if user pass only latude and longtude.

Comment: I doubt it, unit tests should be written according to your project's needs.

Comment: i mean that laittude and longitude test - dont find in ur code